# import existing source code as referenced library in eclipse

Tags: blackberry, build-process

I have some source codes from a friend that I would like to use as referenced library in my BlackBerry project. I'm not sure about how to package the source codes into a .jar file. I tried exporting the source to a JAR file and import it as external JAR in my project, it's giving me missing stack map error. I tried to preverify the .jar file generated from the source using the provided preverification tool from BlackBerry JDE, it didn't give me any output folder.

In fact, I'm not sure if the way I export the source is correct. Can anyone provide step-by-step instructions on how to package existing source code into a valid JAR file that can be imported into my project as a referenced library?

Again, I'm using eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fought with this issue for months...

I have two solutions for you:

**A-If you plan on having this library in more than one Application:**

I posted my solution at the bottom of my original question: [Blackberry Apps - Importing a code-signed jar into an application project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791635/blackberry-apps-importing-a-code-signed-jar-into-an-application-project)

The basic solution was to build the library as a cldc project (plus some other magic), not as a library project.  I actually had to open a case with RIM support to figure this out, it was a hot mess...  Our case was complicated in that more than one application would have a copy of our "Library" and our library had to be signed.  Which caused weird issues when two ALX files (from two different apps) both had the same signed library file.

The nice thing about this solution is that adding the library to the Application doesn't force you to have multiple COD files.

**B - If your Jar is only going to be in one Application:**

Then you should follow these instructions: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Eclipse-1-1-can-I-add-external-3-d-party-JAR-library/m-p/486787#M98033